# Blender 2.8. Render to video file with audio from Video Editing section

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

Blender 2.8. On Ubuntu 19.10

Being in the "Video Editing" section. 
There are have a couple of spides + audio files.
[image]
I want to render to video file.
I do choose the video, format, container, codecs, audio on:

[image]

Then press F12, CTRL+F12?? Nothing happens.

[image]

Thre is no button "render" on anything.

**Q:** How ould I render to Video File with audio?

Comment: Your setup works for me with my sample file, someone suggested AAC for H.264, someone Render Audio separately ... from answers it doesnt seem there is a general issue, rather then some specific to users files. Does issue persist with some short sample too? Try new file with some sample. Probably some track is problematic?

Comment: I tried AAC. Tried on Linux, and Windows 10. Same result. Empty render window. No activities. No output.

Comment: I was able to render. but not for FFMpeg + H.264. But + dVix. the H.264 does not work.
also seems it does not use CPU when rendering much. like 0.01 %. take a lot of time to render 2 slides on Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry I was stack in my box, I understood your issue is video is rendered without Audio. You don't see Render operator? It's too much for comment, I will write "answer" - to be sure of two things ...

Answer (score 2):

Render operator is located in top row of app Render > Render Animation (Ctrl+F12).

[image]

Check if in *Properties Editor* under *Output Properties > Post Processing >* **Sequencer** is enabled.

[image]

If it is not the case attach simplified blend only with a short sample of movie, so we can check. But if you are able to render with different codec I'm not able to help since issue lies somewere in your PC condition.

Comment: I like that star!

Comment: why can't i find "Output Properties"?

Comment: @Michael If you are asking where it is located ... see my edited answer.